# not able to render otp.html in flask in "/" route

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I am not able to render otmp.html in route "/" as if is redirecting to otp route.

```
flask code
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,url_for,redirect

parties=["A","B","C","D"]

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('home.html')
    #return render_template('admin.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def my_form_post():
    if request.method == "POST":
       adhar_no = request.form['aadhar_num']
       return redirect(url_for('verification',adhar_no=adhar_no))
    return render_template('otp.html')  

@app.route('/otp',methods = ['POST','GET'])
def verification():
    a_no=request.args.get('adhar_no')
    otp_text = request.form['otp']
    return render_template('party.html',n_party=parties,n=len(parties))
```

can anyone please help me with how to return redirect and render html page in a same route.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two routes that have the same path and method . The first route will always be called and the second one won't be reached. So to solve your problem please change one of the routes path

**Note: I see the first route to be unnecessary just remove it and use this code instead**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,url_for,redirect

parties=["A","B","C","D"]

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def my_form_post():
    if request.method == "POST":
       adhar_no = request.form['aadhar_num']
       return redirect(url_for('verification',adhar_no=adhar_no))
  return render_template('home.html')
....
```

Comment: Thankx for response but my problem is in second route"/" i need to render OTP.html page and  pass parameters to verification function

Comment: @PSairam you can't have  two routes that have the same path and method . The first route will always be called and the second one won't be reached. So to solve your problem please change one of the routes path.

Comment: @PSairam I have modified my answer check it out.